# Query inside a thread

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, linq-to-entities

I have 3 comboboxes that are loaded with data from LINQ queries on page load. The problem is that queries contain so much data that it causes Internet Explorer to stop responding for a bit more than a minute.

As there are 3 queries my idea is to put them in 3 different threads, but the problem is at the end the only thing I get is the error saying: "Both DataSource and DataSourceID are defined on 'cbOrganizator'.  Remove one definition."

cbOrganizator is a combobox.

Here is the code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Bind();
}

public void Osobe()
    {
        PravosudnaAkademijaEntities db = new PravosudnaAkademijaEntities();

        var osoba = from o in db.osobas
                    orderby o.osoba_prezime
                    select new { o.osoba_id, imePrezime = o.osoba_prezime + " " + o.osoba_ime + " | " + o.tijelo.tijelo_naziv + " | " + o.radno_mjesto.rm_naziv_m };

        cbPolaznik.DataSource = osoba;
        cbPolaznik.DataTextField = "imePrezime";
        cbPolaznik.DataValueField = "osoba_id";
        cbPolaznik.DataBind();
        cbPolaznik.Items.Insert(0, " ");

        cbPredavac.DataSource = osoba;
        cbPredavac.DataTextField = "imePrezime";
        cbPredavac.DataValueField = "osoba_id";
        cbPredavac.DataBind();
        cbPredavac.Items.Insert(0, " ");

        cbAOM.DataSource = osoba;
        cbAOM.DataTextField = "imePrezime";
        cbAOM.DataValueField = "osoba_id";
        cbAOM.DataBind();
        cbAOM.Items.Insert(0, " ");
    }

    public void Tijela()
    {
        PravosudnaAkademijaEntities db = new PravosudnaAkademijaEntities();

        var tijelo = from t in db.tijeloes
                     orderby t.tijelo_naziv
                     select new { t.tijelo_id, sve = t.tijelo_naziv + " | " + t.mjesto.zupanija_drzava.zupanija_naziv };

        cbOrganizator.DataSource = tijelo;
        cbOrganizator.DataTextField = "sve";
        cbOrganizator.DataValueField = "tijelo_id";
        cbOrganizator.DataBind();
        cbOrganizator.Items.Insert(0, " ");
    }

    public void Bind()
    {
         Thread tOsobe = new Thread(Osobe);
         tOsobe.Start();
         Thread tTijela = new Thread(Tijela);
         tTijela.Start();
    }
```

I don't know what's wrong so any help would be appreciated. The primary idea is to separate queries into threads so if my approach is wrong please let me know.

Comment: you should join threads.

Comment: That's the solution! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You're starting threads but not giving them a chance to finish before the page is loaded. I don't know how that results in your particular error, but if your page loads before the thread is completed, then you definitely won't get results.

I really don't see how you'll be able to accomplish what you're trying to do without AJAX.

Comment: That probably is the problem. Could you be more precise about accomplishing it with AJAX. Thank you in advance!

Comment: You could probably do it with an Update Panel, but I've never liked them. If it was me, I'd probably load the page with an empty dropdown box, with some kind of "working" indicator. I'd have a [PageMethod] static method that returns a list of key-value objects, and have jQuery initiate the request immediately, and upon its return, populate the dropdown. The method I use is basically the one from this site: [http://encosia.com/2008/05/29/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/](http://encosia.com/2008/05/29/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/)

Comment: The only reason I tried to do something different than the code I currently have is bad performance in Internet Explorer (other browsers perform normally). Currently I'm using  AJAX Control Toolkit and Combobox is one of its controls. I've even tried changing AJAX CT combobox to Telerik's RadTools Combobox, but the result was pretty much the same. The problem seems to be that IE doesn't handle well binding 3 times 5000 records to combobox. Other browsers do...

Comment: Ouch, that's a lot of records for a combobox. You may want to consider changing that to some kind of filterable list, if not for performance, then at least for usability. As a user, I don't think I'd like that many options in my dropdown.

Comment: I know, I wouldn't want to have also so much records in my combobox, but, that's exactly what the user wanted.

Answer (score 1):

if you do really want to do it with threads i would suggest performing the query on the threadpool. you can abstract your method so that it is called in delegate of the threadpool method
so i would replace bind with

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(Osobe));
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(Tijela));
```

change signature of Osobe, and Tijela to acccept a Object
eg.public void Osobe(object a )

you will also need to marshal the call across the thread as i am not sure if webforms will accept if the binding is happening on another thread.

All said and done is still feel the ajax method is the best way forward.